# Ever Ascending Melody

Tags: theory, technique

I once heard of a melody that, when played, sounds like it is always ascending. Is that a thing? Please explain.

Comment: You are probably thinking about the "Shepard tone" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepard_tone

Comment: *Shepard tone* should be the answer.

Comment: It's not that tune about a lark, is it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shepard tones (as noted before) are an example.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepard_tone

Basically, one plays 12 tones (fundamental and 11 overtones) for each note. Eleven of the tones move up a semitone and the other one moves down 11 semitones.